# Passing data to a handler, from another class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, handler, ioio

I have a `Handler` that is in my `MainActivity`. This `Handler` has to update the UI of one of my `Fragment`s inside of the `MainActivity`'s layout.

I then have a separate class that has a loop; when I create this class, let's called it `myLooper` it does some sort of calculation then send the information inside of the loop to the `Handler` in my `MainActivity`. Which in turn will then update that data onto a `GraphView` that I have implemented within my `MainActivity`'s Fragment.

FLOW:
Step 1: Calculate data on `MyLooper`.
Step 2: Send data to `MainActivity` via my `Handler`.
Step 3: Have my `Handler` update `MainActivity`'s `Fragment`'s `GraphView` with the sent data.

Relevant code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {


    public MyLooper myDataLooper;
    Fragment graphFrag = fragment_graphpage.newInstance(1);
    public final Handler myHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                ((fragment_graphpage) graphFrag).updateGraphUI(msg.getData().getFloat("myvoltage"));
            }
        };
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    globalControlInstance globalControl;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        globalControl = globalControlInstance.getInstance();

        myDataLooper = (IOIOBoard) getApplicationContext();
        myDataLooper.create(getBaseContext(), this,_myIOIOHandler);
        myDataLooper.start();
 }
```

MyLooper class:

```
public class MyLooper extends Application implements IOIOLooperProvider {


    globalControlInstance globalData = globalControlInstance.getInstance();
    public AnalogInput AI1;
    public Handler IOIOHandler;
    private final IOIOAndroidApplicationHelper helper_ = new IOIOAndroidApplicationHelper(
            this, this);

    protected void create(Context myContext, Activity myActivity, Handler myHandler) {
        IOIOHandler = myHandler;
        helper_.create();
    }

    protected void destroy() {
        helper_.destroy();
    }

    protected void start() {
        helper_.start();
    }

    protected void stop() {
        helper_.stop();
    }

    protected void restart() {
        helper_.restart();
    }

    class Looper extends BaseIOIOLooper {

        @Override
        protected void setup() throws ConnectionLostException {

        }

        @Override
        public void loop() throws ConnectionLostException, InterruptedException {
            Message myVoltageMessage = new Message();
            Bundle myVoltageBundle = new Bundle();
            myVoltageBundle.putFloat("myvoltage", AI1.getVoltage());
            myVoltageMessage.setData(myVoltageBundle);
            IOIOHandler.sendMessage(myVoltageMessage);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IOIOLooper createIOIOLooper(String connectionType, Object extra) {
        return new Looper();
    }


}
```

Finally the `Fragment` that contains my `GraphView`'s `updateGraphUI` method.:

```
public void updateGraphUI(float newReading) {
    final double newReadingDouble = newReading;
        mTimer2 = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                graphLoopCounter++;

                if (globalData.isLiveUpdatingEnabled()) {
                alarmCheck(newReadingDouble);
                globalData.setGraph2LastXValue(globalData
                        .getGraph2LastXValue() + 1d);
                globalData.getGraphViewSeries().appendData(
                        new GraphViewData(globalData.getGraph2LastXValue(),
                                newValue), true, 1000);
                if (globalData.getGraphPeak() < newReadingDouble) {
                    globalData.setGraphPeak(newReadingDouble);
                    graphPeak.setText("Graph Peak: "
                            + Double.toString(newReadingDouble));
                }


                    avgSum += globalData.getLatestGraphData();
                        graphAvg.setText("Graph Avg: " + Double.toString(avgSum/graphLoopCounter));


                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
                }
            }
        };
        mHandler.postDelayed(mTimer2, 100);

}
```

where `mHandler` is a handler in my `Fragment`'s implementation. and both `mTimer1` and `mTimer2` are `Runnable`s.

my problem is; no matter what I try to do data is not sent to my GraphView and it never updates...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MainActivity you name your Handler instance "myHandler" but then you pass your MyLooper class "_myIOIOHandler".